# How do I remove the multiple "Attribute not allowed here error" when I start a new document?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to make a simple Happy Birthday Card. Whenever I start the application and create a new project I receive a number of errors in the Activity_Main.xml file that prevents me from seeing the preview.

I've tried reinstalling Java, Reinstalling Android Studio, Checking the proxy's, Changing the layout from Constraint to Relative and Opening and closing the XML files.

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
     <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Birthday YOURFRIENDHERE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It was Code given to simply display text on the screen of a phone however I keep receiving errors on all of the attributes, Android:layout, Tools:context, and TextView saying they're not allowed. Even when I create a new project and haven't edited anything I still get the errors on the code that's automatically populated.

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Happy Birthday YOURFRIENDHERE" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>  FULL CODE

Comment: Don't post your additional code/XML in a comment, edit your question and add it there. Also, specify exactly what kinds of errors you are receiving. Have you tried building/running your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Birthday YOURFRIENDHERE" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is still not working, I've managed to see that Gradle is failing to connect, I've tried manually installing Gradle & creating a Path, I can verify Gradle is running in CMD however I'm still not able to connect to Gradle through Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It was a VPN issue, certain files were not being received from google and as a result the necessary files weren't being accessed. All is working as expected now!

Answer (score 0):

I think it was because the version of your android studio is not up-to-date , as I think google want us to use an up-to-date version when you found you are blocking from download the gradle resource from the internet through your android studio .